# How Apache Mina SignalListner works?

Tags: java, ssh, sigint, apache-mina

I want to terminate the Apache Mina Ssh Server on the basis of **Ctrl+c** that are basically `SigInt` I searched on the google and have looked there are `SignalListener` but not find any good example of it.

Please share any good example and use in **ssh server**.

A listener  will only trigger if any Sigint or a Signal is sent, Am I right ?

Comment: Did you manage to catch the Ctrl + C? I am have the same question haha

Answer (score 0):

To get access to signal handling you have to use sun's private classes, which makes your code not portable any mode. Anyway...

```
    import sun.misc.Signal;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        registerSignalHandler();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
    private static void registerSignalHandler() {
        Signal.handle(new Signal("HUP"), (Signal signal) -> {
             System.out.println("Hello signal!");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want specifically to Apache mina sshd server.
And I want to work with `Sigs`.